# Unable to add properly multiple lines for different products on google chart

Tags: javascript

I have two groups of checkboxes: Countries and Products/Indicators. I'm trying to get to work with two cases:

1. select 1 country + many products
2. select many countries + 1 product

Case 2 is working fine but case 1 `1 country + many products` it doesn't work okay.

There are two problems that I saw:

1. When I click on one country and select one product the graph is loaded. Then I can check one more product or 10 more. I want to have separate lines for each product that is selected. The problem is that currently, I have one line for all products that are selected. They are appended to the current line which shows false lines/bars on the graph.
2. If I deselect some products from the ones that are already selected, the data that is shown on the chart is not removed. All data for every product click is appended to the current line and never removed if I deselect that product. I guess this will be fixed if point 1) got fixed because then will remove the line for this product from the chart.

So, here is what I have so far for submit:

```
            var countriesIDs = {};
            var indicatorURL = "";
            
            $.each(countriesIDs, function(key,id) {
                    var name = "#countryCheckbox"+id;
                    $(name).attr("checked",true);
                }
            );

            var selectedStartMonth = $("#selectedStartMonth").val().toString().padStart(2, '0');
            var startFilter = parseInt($("#startFilter").val()); 
            var selectedEndMonth = $("#selectedEndMonth").val().toString().padStart(2, '0');
            var endFilter = parseInt($("#endFilter").val()); 
            var period = selectedStartMonth + ":" + startFilter + "-" + selectedEndMonth + ":" + endFilter;

            $("#submitFilters").click(function () {
                $.post("/ajax/comparison_data.php", {
                    countriesIDs: countriesIDs,
                    indicatorURL: indicatorURL,
                    period: period,
                },
                function (result) {
                    try {
                        var chartData = result.data;
                        var indicatorTitles = result.indicatorTitles;
                        var startYear = result.startYear;
                        var endYear = result.endYear;
            
                        var graphTitle = indicatorTitles.join(" | ");
            
                        var startYearOnGraph = parseInt(startYear);
                        var data_end_year = parseInt(endYear);
                        $("#startFilter").val(startYearOnGraph);
                        $("#endFilter").val(data_end_year);
            
                        countries_names = [];
                        Object.keys(chartData).forEach(year => {
                            var yearData = chartData[year];
                            yearData.forEach(item => {
                                var countryName = item[2];
                                if (!countries_names.includes(countryName)) {
                                    countries_names.push(countryName);
                                }
                            });
                        });              
            
                        drawChart(chartData, countries_names, graphTitle, startYearOnGraph);
                    } catch (error) {
                        console.error("Error parsing JSON:", error);
                        $("#chart_div").html("<div style='padding-left:100px; padding-top:20px; height:400px; width:600px; font-size:16px;'>An error occurred while fetching data. Please try again later.</div>");
                    }
                }, "json");
            });
```

And this is my drawing function:

```
var data = null; // Initialize data as null

function drawChart(chartData, countries_names, graphTitle, startYear) {
  var dataMap = {};

  Object.keys(chartData).forEach(year => {
    var yearData = chartData[year];
    yearData.forEach(function (item) {
      var month = item[0];
      var dataValue = parseFloat(item[1]);
      var indicatorTitle = item[2];

      if (!dataMap[year]) {
        dataMap[year] = {};
      }

      if (!dataMap[year][month]) {
        dataMap[year][month] = {};
      }

      dataMap[year][month][indicatorTitle] = dataValue;
    });
  });

  if (!data) {
    data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Year/Month');
    countries_names.forEach(function (country) {
      data.addColumn('number', country);
    });
  }

  var formattedDataRows = [];
  var years = Object.keys(dataMap);
  years.forEach(function (year) {
    var months = Object.keys(dataMap[year]);
    months.forEach(function (month) {
      var rowData = [];
      rowData.push(`${year}/${month}`);
      countries_names.forEach(function (country) {
        var indicatorsData = [];
        Object.keys(dataMap[year][month]).forEach(function (indicatorTitle) {
          // Check if the indicator title contains the selected country name
          if (indicatorTitle.toLowerCase().includes(country.toLowerCase())) {
            indicatorsData.push(dataMap[year][month][indicatorTitle]);
          }
        });
        var averageValue = indicatorsData.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0) / indicatorsData.length;
        rowData.push(averageValue || null);
      });
      formattedDataRows.push(rowData);
    });
  });

  data.addRows(formattedDataRows);

  var numIndicators = countries_names.length;
  var colors = generateColors(numIndicators);

  var options = {
    width: graphWidth,
    height: graphHeight,
    title: graphTitle,
    legend: {
      position: 'bottom'
    },
    colors: colors
  };

  var chart;
  if (chartType === 'Line') {
    chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  } else if (chartType === 'Column') {
    chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  } else if (chartType === 'Bar') {
    chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  }

  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

By the fact that the graph shows data, I believe that the backend is working correctly and returning correct data. I just can't get it to work on the graph.

Here is an example of data for country Australia and products Flour and Rice:

```
data: {2022: [["3", "1.25", "Australia"], ["6", "1.19", "Australia"], ["9", "1.15", "Australia"],…],…}
2022: [["3", "1.25", "Australia"], ["6", "1.19", "Australia"], ["9", "1.15", "Australia"],…]
0: ["3", "1.25", "Australia"]
1: ["6", "1.19", "Australia"]
2: ["9", "1.15", "Australia"]
3: ["12", "1.15", "Australia"]
4: ["3", "2", "Australia"]
5: ["6", "2.4", "Australia"]
6: ["9", "2.4", "Australia"]
7: ["12", "2.4", "Australia"]
2023: [["3", "1.15", "Australia"], ["3", "2.4", "Australia"]]
0: ["3", "1.15", "Australia"]
1: ["3", "2.4", "Australia"]
endYear: "2022"
indicatorTitles: ["Flour price, 1 kg,1 kg", "Rice price, 1 kg,1 kg"]
0: "Flour"
1: "Rice"
startYear: "2022"
```